# Small and Big Riddle

Tags: riddle

> When small, my tail down.
>       When big, my tail is up.
>
> When small, I can not be seen.
>       When big, I look small in big.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you..

> The letter G.

Because...

> Small g has a tail that hangs down, upper case it sorta curves towards. The g in "big" is small because it appears at the end. There is no g in the word "Small".

Comment: ahhh, nice one! +1

Comment: You got it! .any feedback ? because this is my first riddle.

Comment: @Q̞ī̯X̶͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇̯̯̳̳͈͈͈͆͆ It was a simple, fun riddle! Thank you for sharing with us.

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> The Letter I?

When small, my tail down.

> I believe you are referring to the horizontal line at the bottom and top of the capitalized letter I. When it is lowercase, it does not appear.

When big, my tail is up.

> Again, this refers to the horizontal line that normally appears in the capitalized version of I

When small, I can not be seen.

> The capitalized version of I cannot be seen when it is lowercase.

When big, I look small in big

> I believe this is a play on words. In the word big, 'i' is not capitalized, but is lowercase or small.

Comment: Nice ,,but the answer is wrong